# NetBeans - The module has not been deployed

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

Im trying to run a java web project from netbeans, everything went fine yesterday, but today when I tried running it again i got an error :

```
ant -f F:\\אינטרנט\\OfficalProject -Dnb.internal.action.name=redeploy -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=F:\\אינטרנט\\OfficalProject run-deploy
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1
GlassFish Server 4.1 is running.
In-place deployment at F:\אינטרנט\OfficalProject\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
F:\אינטרנט\OfficalProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

I have searched for a solution but everything i read didnt work, finally I uninstalled netbeans and glassfish from my PC and installed it again, I tried running the project, and it worked, but after i closed netbeans and tried again, the same thing happend.

Server Log:

```
[2015-05-29T17:33:20.142+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998600] [timeMillis: 1432910000142] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.146+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998600] [timeMillis: 1432910000146] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.276+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998614] [timeMillis: 1432910000276] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.280+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998614] [timeMillis: 1432910000280] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.286+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998614] [timeMillis: 1432910000286] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.414+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998613] [timeMillis: 1432910000414] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.450+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998600] [timeMillis: 1432910000450] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.610+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998614] [timeMillis: 1432910000610] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.735+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998597] [timeMillis: 1432910000735] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 77ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.763+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998597] [timeMillis: 1432910000763] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 7ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.786+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998597] [timeMillis: 1432910000786] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 14ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:20.828+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998614] [timeMillis: 1432910000828] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 6ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:22.145+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1432910002145] [levelValue: 800] [[
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (34,672ms), startup services(3,562ms), total(38,234ms)]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:22.381+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=60 _ThreadName=Thread-12] [timeMillis: 1432910002381] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Golan-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://Golan-PC:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:22.556+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1432909998597] [timeMillis: 1432910002556] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 8ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:22.567+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1432910002567] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@aa375c as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@72947a.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:23.829+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=pool-12-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1432910003829] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 23ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:24.109+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=pool-15-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1432910004109] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 33ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:27.762+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910007762] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.210+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01002] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008210] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Java security manager is disabled.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.210+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01010] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008210] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Entering Security Startup Service.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.215+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01143] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008215] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.263+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01011] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008263] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Security Service(s) started successfully.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.646+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008646] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.652+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008652] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.655+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008655] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.680+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008680] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server server]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.682+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008682] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server __asadmin]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.874+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-CORE-00306] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008874] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:28.875+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00201] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910008875] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Virtual server server loaded default web module ]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:29.479+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910009479] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:29.572+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910009572] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:29.608+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-DEPLOYMENT-00001] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910009608] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /F:/אינטרנט/OfficalProject/build/web/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:31.041+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910011041] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [OfficalProject] at [/]]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:31.116+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1432910011116] [levelValue: 800] [[
  OfficalProject was successfully deployed in 3,727 milliseconds.]]

[2015-05-29T17:33:40.196+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1432910020196] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /]]

[2015-05-29T17:34:46.229+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1432910086229] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-05-29T17:34:46.463+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1432910086463] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-05-29T17:34:46.482+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1432910086482] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-05-29T17:34:46.503+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-DEPLOYMENT-00001] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1432910086503] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/Golan/Desktop/homePage/homePage/build/web/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.]]

[2015-05-29T17:34:46.719+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1432910086719] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [Segev] at [/Segev]]]

[2015-05-29T17:34:46.753+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1432910086753] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Segev was successfully deployed in 587 milliseconds.]]

[2015-05-29T17:37:26.115+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00092] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=134 _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1432910246115] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server shutdown initiated]]

[2015-05-29T17:37:26.118+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00028] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=134 _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1432910246118] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@aa375c from service registry.]]

[2015-05-29T17:37:26.118+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=134 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1432910246118] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FileMonitoring shutdown]]

[2015-05-29T17:37:26.123+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00002] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=134 _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1432910246123] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null]]

[2015-05-29T17:37:26.123+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00001] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=134 _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1432910246123] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.]]

[2015-05-29T17:37:26.366+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=144 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1432910246366] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool]]]
```

Any solutions?
Thank You All!!

Comment: The message indicates that Glassfish is either not running or there is a different problem during deployment. Please update the question with the contents of your `server.log`.

Comment: @unwichtich Alright, please look now. Thank you

Comment: Hmm, the log doesn't show any real problems...maybe you can try to put your project into a folder without UTF-8 characters, possibly this is a problem for some part of the software stack.

Comment: @unwichtich You mean like this directory : F:\Internet\OfficalProject ? still doesnt work.

Comment: Yes...but then I don't know what the problem is. Maybe you can try to deploy it again and see if something different (some kind of error message) is logged in the `server.log`.